# pushing a div down to the bottom of the page

Tags: css

I' cant for the life of me figure out why the div "book_button" won't display at the bottom of the page, above the footer. I have a main wrapper div, and then there is a content div. I've placed the book_button in a relative position outside the content div. In the dream weaver design window it's showing it where I want it to be. When I view it in a browser it diplays like so

http://kerrydean.ca/GreyRiver/fly_fishing.html

here is the css

```
#Wrapper {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 75px;
}
#Header {
    background-color: #b2b85c;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
#Content {
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#Left_Side {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 485px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
#Right_Side {
    width: 340px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    height: 100%;
}
#Footer {
    background-color: #BCC271;
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
/* Navigation*/
.nav-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 900px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 31px;
}
ul#navlist
{
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#navlist li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navlist a {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#navlist a:link, #navlist a:visited
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b2b85c;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: dotted;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
}

#navlist a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b2b85c;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(../GreyRiver/Images/pointer.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% bottom;
}
.border-none{
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;    
    }
/*End of Navigation*/
#header_img{
    height: 250px;
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../GreyRiver/Images/Fly_fishing_header.jpg);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#book_button{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I figured it out.

I put the book_button div right before the footer. I made the width 100%, position:relative and add a float:left

thanks anyway!

Comment: Looking at your source, you have #book_button with a position absolute not relative.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make #Wrapper `position:relative`

2) make #book_button `position:absolute`, set `bottom:40px;right:200px;`

Comment: It's probably just a matter of tweaking the position values.

Comment: Position absolute will do 40px from the bottom of the browser window not the content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't best practice, but you could use the `top` style property to push the button down where you want it. It looks like the content of your page is static, meaning that button isn't going to need to position itself dynamically each time the page loads. So, a hard coded value to position it may work for you.

Comment: @Diodeus' answer is probably better - but yeah, hard coding the position in your case is probably the way to go.

Comment: thanks as well. But this option is not going to work for me either. I puzzled as to why the content div doesnt force the book_button div directly under it. It's still inside the wrapper? I'm baffled

Answer (score 0):

I took your current view source and just changed the #book_button back to relative and it displays in between the footer and the content. Change that back to relative as absolute will not work.